# Swift 3 Local notifications not firing

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, uilocalnotification

I have the following setup and no notification are firing at all.

Based on other similar questions on the stack, I've put in a unique identifier for each request and I've also added the body to the content.

I've got this function which requests permission from user.

```
    func sendIntNotifications()
        {
            //1.  Request permission from the user
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound], completionHandler:
                {
                    (granted, error) in

                    if granted
                    {
                        print ("Notification access granted")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print(error?.localizedDescription)
                    }

                    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
                })
// This function has a lot of other code that then calls this function to set multiple notifications :


            for daysInt in outputWeekdays
            {
                scheduleActualNotification(hourInt: hourInt, minuteInt: minuteInt, dayInt: daysInt)
            }
        }
```

And these are the main function :

```
func scheduleActualNotification(hourInt hour: Int, minuteInt minute: Int, dayInt day: Int)
    {
        // 3.1 create date components for each day
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()

        dateComponents.hour = hour
        dateComponents.minute = minute
        dateComponents.day = day

        //3.2 Create a calendar trigger for that day at that time
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents,
                                                    repeats: true)

        //3.3 Message content
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Test Title"
        content.body = "Test body"
        content.badge = 1

        // 3.4 Create the actual notification
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "bob \(i+1)",
                                            content: content,
                                            trigger: trigger)
        // 3.5 Add our notification to the notification center
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
        {
            (error) in
            if let error = error
            {
                print("Uh oh! We had an error: \(error)")
            }
        }

    }
```

This function is to receive the notification when this app is open

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    completionHandler([.alert, .sound]) //calls the completionHandler indicating that both the alert and the sound is to be presented to the user
}
```

There are no errors either lol!

**Edit :**

So from the user interface, I selected 2350 and Saturday and Sunday. I expect the notification to be sent at 2350 on both Saturday and Sunday.

I did `print(daysInt)`. The first value of it is 1 and the second value of it is 7 which is just as expected. Secondly, I went into the function `scheduleActualNotification` and the values of hour was 23 and minute was 50, just as expected.

Thank you!

Comment: If your app is in background...do you still get the alert? If yes then you've added the notification correctly, but aren't handling it correctly ie if it doesn't work correct for when the app is in foreground then then likely the object that you've set as your delegate with `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = YOUROBJECT` isn't the same object that wrote the `willPresent` function on ie you 'adopted' with one class but 'conformed' in another. Put a breakpoint on `completionHandler([.alert, .sound])` and see if it's ever getting called. My guess is that it never gets called.

Comment: But right now you haven't shown **which class** you added the request nor have shown from which class you're handling it. Please show that in your code so we can better help you

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your response. There are no notifications at all - neither in the background nor in the foreground.

All of this code is in the `ViewController.swift` file and the class begins like this :
`import UIKit`
`import UserNotifications`


`class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,` `UITableViewDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`
`{`

Comment: So since you said you're not getting any errors, the only issue I could think of is that the time you're passing is incorrect. Show us an example of what you're passing to your `scheduleActualNotification` func. As a good way to validate the time you're passing. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42218152/5175709) answer

Comment: Hi, I put in a breakpoint and the time is being passed correctly. I also noticed as you pointed out that the code is never entering `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound], completionHandler:` But this is quite strange as the notification is coming, asking the user for permission to send notifications.

Comment: Don't assume it's passed correctly. Kindly edit your question and show what's in your `outputWeekdays`. It's not strange. You could be correctly passing a trigger of 5 years and never getting it.

Comment: Also in your edit, print the time of the calendar and tell us what you expect it to be.

Comment: My point is give us ALL needed data so we could reproduce the issue. Without knowing your `outputWeekdays` we can't reproduce it on our own and obviously can't help you

Comment: Just updated my question. I printed the values of `daysInt` which are values of `outputWeekdays`.

Comment: My idea is that Sunday is passed as '1', Monday as 2, all the way to Saturday which is 7 for  `dateComponents.day `

Comment: Do you think it has anything to do with the fact that the code is never entering `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(opti‌​ons: `[.alert, .badge, .sound], completionHandler:` ? I also added `dateComponents.year = 2017` and that didn't help either. Thanks.

Comment: You mean your neither getting granted nor getting error? If that's case then likely the you've disabled notifications for the entire device or that app. Have you verified that?

Comment: I apologise, it is going into that piece of the code. I am very sorry I didn't check it properly. So the console is printing "Notification access granted". Do you kindly have any other pointers please ?

Comment: I just went into Capabilities and clicked on On for Push notifications. That didn't help either unfortunately.

Comment: Hi, do you have any other suggestions please ?

Comment: If you want help then please provide exactly what's inside `outputWeekdays` . And how you pass daysInt's data into `scheduleActualNotification(hourInt: hourInt, minuteInt: minuteInt, dayInt: daysInt)`. Share everything. I'll take a look in 2-3 hours

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Kindly see the edit in the original question. I printed `daysInt` which is basically values of `outputWeekdays`. Also kindly see the last part of  `func sendIntNotifications()` where `scheduleActualNotification` is called. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after weeks of frustration, this is the solution :

Replace `dateComponents.day  = day` with `dateComponents.weekday = day`. `.day` is for day of the month whereas `.weekday` is day of the week!

Also do not use `dateComponents.year = 2017` as that caused the notifications not to fire.

The notifications work perfectly fine now!!

Answer (score 0):

Calendar Unit Flags can help you :

```
var notificationTriggerCalendar : UNCalendarNotificationTrigger? = nil

if let fireDate = trigger.remindAt {

  let unitFlags = Set<Calendar.Component>([.hour, .year, .minute, .day, .month, .second])
  var calendar = Calendar.current
  calendar.timeZone = .current
  let components = calendar.dateComponents(unitFlags, from: fireDate)
  let newDate = Calendar.current.date(from: components)

  notificationTriggerCalendar = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.init(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
}
```